# How to show filtered view using query string?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, odata, xrm

Using following url, I am very much able to see list of all contacts,

```
http://mycrm/user01/main.aspx?etn=contact&Pagetype=entitylist
```

Now I want to filter entity list programatically, for example I want to see only contact(s) where '**telephone1**' is 123.

Is it possible to pass OData or other query string in url to get filter list?

I tried to use extraqs but it seems to be working only with entityrecord.

I am using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to pass OData or other query string in url to get filter list?

No, you can't.

You have to build a custom solution, a html webresource.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an XML or JSON list using the OData service. You probably want something like this

/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/ContactSet?$filter=substringof('123',Telephone1)

Or

/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/ContactSet?$filter=telephone1 eq '123'

There is some good documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309461.aspx

be careful, some of the syntax is bizarre (eg, substring and starts with have reversed inputs)